# I am trying to upgrade angular 12 to 14 but I am getting this issue in GitLab pipeline ng-toolkit/universal

Tags: gitlab, pipeline, angular12, angular14, angular14upgrade

> ```
> npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
> npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
> npm ERR! 
> npm ERR! While resolving: @ng-toolkit/universal@8.0.3
> npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@14.1.0
> npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
> npm ERR!   @angular/common@"^14.1.0" from the root project
> npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@"^14.0.0 || ^15.0.0" from @angular/cdk@14.1.0
> npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/cdk
> npm ERR!     @angular/cdk@"^14.1.0" from the root project
> npm ERR!     peer @angular/cdk@"14.1.0" from @angular/material@14.1.0
> npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/material
> npm ERR!       @angular/material@"^14.1.0" from the root project
> npm ERR!   13 more (@angular/forms, @angular/material, ...)
> npm ERR! 
> npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
> npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^8.2.6" from @ng-toolkit/universal@8.0.3
> npm ERR! node_modules/@ng-toolkit/universal
> npm ERR!   @ng-toolkit/universal@"^8.0.3" from the root project
> npm ERR! 
> npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/common@8.2.14
> npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
> npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@"^8.2.6" from @ng-toolkit/universal@8.0.3
> npm ERR!   node_modules/@ng-toolkit/universal
> npm ERR!     @ng-toolkit/universal@"^8.0.3" from the root project
> npm ERR! 
> npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
> npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
> npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
> npm ERR! 
> npm ERR! See /root/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-09-11T07_44_47_296Z-debug-0.l
> ```

I am getting this error in pipeline, but local build working fine.

Node v16 and Angular 14.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This package `@ng-toolkit/universal` is far behind the current version of angular.

You should use @nguniversal instead: https://angular.io/guide/universal